# How to bypass basic authentication in Safari 10 with Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, safaridriver, safari

I have been researching about how to bypass browser authentication in Safari 10 (or Chrome) in Mac OS Sierra. I have tried the following: `http://username:password@URLofAPP`
I have also tried: `alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials(username,password); alert.accept();` and it won't work. Currently using Selenium 3.3 and Safari 10

Comment: Why you are trying to bypass it? You have selenium, you can simulate user logging in.

Comment: I am not sure how to get into the browser alert authentication that safari is throwing. I have done some steps to do it which is the alert.setauthenticationcredentials but I couldn't get into it

Comment: Simulate exactly what user does to login to your website: go to URL, fill login form, submit. Is your website different?

Comment: I am talking about the basic auth on browser level, not the app itself @peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done in Selenium (outside of Java's Robot class), but you can configure your test system(s) to login using Apple's Keychain as this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/343235/476383) points out. As a follow up answer points out, you can do wildcard matches on the domains now.

Comment: I was looking at Applescript where I can just call this method and so when my code detects it is a safari browser I'm testing, the applescript is automatically executed

Comment: @Marj any luck bypassing basic authentication?

Comment: @RiteshKarwa No I didn'thave any luck. Per kirbycope's answer https://superuser.com/questions/343231/how-do-i-make-safari-automatically-use-a-particular-client-certificate-for-an-en/343235#343235 this may help. I did not continue my automation testing due to Professional reasons.